# facebook ads give java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, facebook

Recently I published my app on play store and I am using facebook ads in my app but today I got a crash report in PlayConsole says **ProGuard deobfuscation**

**Upload your ProGuard deobfuscation file in order to deobfuscate future stack traces for this APK version.**

I don't know the what I am missing please help me experts..
Thanks..

**here is the crash report**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: 
      at com.facebook.ads.internal.r.a$b.run (Unknown Source)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6123)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:867)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: did you check out the changelog already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have enabled ProGuard (also known as Minify) in your project. If you have `minifyEnabled true` in your build.gradle file, then you have ProGuard enabled.

Play Console asks you to send a ProGuard mapping file to see what "real" stack trace from your app crash. If you didn't uploaded mapping file, stack trace will look strange (ex. no real class or methods names).
Upload this file so Play Console can "map" the stack trace and you will be able to understand it.

1. Open play console and open your app project. On the left you have "Android Vitals" section
2. In this section there is a place where you can upload your mapping files. Mapping files can be found in: `build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt`

Hope it helped